# Problem driving MOSFET with ACPL 337J optocoupler

Tags: mosfet, ltspice, mosfet-driver, powermosfet

I want to drive a [mosfet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stf27n60m2-ep.pdf). I am using an [ACPL 337J optocoupler](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/678/V02-4390EN_DS_ACPL-337J_2014-05-09-909393.pdf) to drive it. Here is the schematic:-

[image: Schematic]

But I am facing problem while driving the mosfet. The signal at gate of mosfet should be a PWM but the signal at gate is nothing like a PWM.

[image: Vgate].

Also the drain to source characterstics look something like this:[image: Vdrain.]
Please suggest edits in the schematic so as to get the desired result. Also if required, I can provide schematic.

PS: I am simulating the circuit in LTSpice XVII

-------------------------X-----------------------X------------------------------

I generated the mosfet's symbol and now used it in the circuit.[image: New schematic]. But the plots are same after simulation.

The testing circuit as provided in the application note-
[image: testingckt]

The circuit I simulated-

[image: simulated]

And the error-

[image: eorror]

If you want the error list of the simulation, you can find it [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mDuzmooKcvCSA9WJfDHk_7f9i78sEWEV/view?usp=sharing).

------------------X---------------------X--------------------

Here is the new schematic. I joined VE to source of mosfet.
[image: all_new]

Now the plot looks something like this (the simulation was stuck at 40%, so I had to halt the simulation.):

[image: plot]

Plots after grounding Cathode:

[image: 3_plots]

[image: Final plot]

Comment: It looks as if you included the MOS library, but didn't correctly adjusted the actual MOS in the schematic (talking about renaming, maybe also the `x` prefix), if needed. You should also use some models for the diodes instead of the default ones (a `.model d d is=1f`, with or without `cjo=1p` should do as a minimum. Maybe I'm nitpicking, but tidying up the connections a bit will only help with debugging.

Comment: compare the netlists of both circuits and search for differences

Comment: Does your optocoupler model work fine by itself?

Comment: @Huisman There is no difference between the two netlists.

Comment: @winny Please can you explain your question? I did not get it.

Comment: If you would take away your MOSFET and other circitry and just have your ACPL 337J optocoupler, ideal bias (voltage source), ideal load (resistor) and ideal input, do you get the output you expect? I.e. are you sure it's the MOSFET model which is the problem in the first place?

Comment: @winny MOSFET model is not a problem. There is something wrong in the circuit itself. I am not able to rectify it. PS:I have to use this MOSFET model only, so I will have to make necessary changes in the circuit.

Comment: Right. But can you please make a test bench for the optocopler itself?

Comment: What happens if you connect VEE1  to ground?.

Comment: @BruceAbbott In which circuit? In the second circuit, there is no change and the simulation throws the same error. In the first circuit, I edited the connections. I connected Ve pin to source of mosfet. And connected VEE1 to ground. Please find the plot and schematic in the updated question.

Comment: @winny Please find the images in the updated question.

Comment: Getting somewhere! You can open the U1 symbol and check which pin is named gate or x13, but to me it looks like LTspice is complaining that something is floating. Try grounding cathode and skip the 1500 V impulse withstand test. Focus on getting the correct gate drive from primary to secondary in your test bench circuit.

Comment: You need to ground the junction of C2, C3, and R2. Where can we get your spice model for the ACP337J?

Comment: @BruceAbbott If you want the spice model of ACPL 337J please go [here].(https://www.broadcom.com/products/optocouplers/industrial-plastic/isolated-gate-drive-optocouplers/highly-integrated-smart-gate-drives/acpl-337j-000e#downloads) There find  and download SPICE model. Open the file in LTspice. Right click on the subcircuit statement and click Create symbol. Save it. Now you can find the model in Autogenerated folder of LTspice.

Comment: @winny Thankyou. Now there is some pulse across gate. But the voltage goes beyond 7V and ACPL 337J shuts down. Please find the plots in the updated question.

Comment: Get rid of C8. It looks like the desaturation pin is disabled by being grounded (near C6), so that *shouldn't* be causing the driver to deactivate. Not sure if your desaturation diode (UN4007) is up to the job - that's usually a slow diode.

Comment: IT WORKED!!! I connected a schottky diode (MBR0540) between DESAT and VE pin. The other details are in the updated question.